# Drag and drop for more the one text box

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In the following code Im having list box for 2 text box ,currently its working but I have two question

1.suppose I need to drag for more than 2 text box ,instead of copy the code can I write it 
in dynamic way to support 5 text box for instance ?

**this is the code for the two text boxes**

```
private void textbox1_PreviewDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string name = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat).ToString();
    textbox1.Text += name;
    textbox1.Focus();
    textbox1.CaretIndex = textbox1.Text.Length;
    e.Handled = true;
    _UsersList.Remove((User) listbox1.SelectedItem);

}

private void textbox2_PreviewDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string name = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat).ToString();
    textbox2.Text += name;
    textbox2.Focus();
    textbox2.CaretIndex = textbox2.Text.Length;
    e.Handled = true;
    bool remove = _UsersList.Remove((User)listbox1.SelectedItem);
}
```

**The second question** in the following code I check if the text box already have value,if so its not allowed to drag (the Or statement for text box 1 & 2 )
another value to it  ,there is better way to write it if i will have more than 2 text boxes?

```
private void listbox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0 && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox2.Text)))
    {
        if (listbox1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            var mySelectedItem = listbox1.SelectedItem as  User;
```

...
            }
        }
    }

**in the xaml**

```
 <TextBox x:Name="textbox1"  
                  AcceptsReturn="True"
                  AllowDrop="True" 
                  DragOver="textbox1_DragOver"
                  PreviewDrop="textbox1_PreviewDrop" 

      <TextBox x:Name="textbox2"  
                  AcceptsReturn="True"
                  AllowDrop="True" 
                  DragOver="textbox2_DragOver"
                  PreviewDrop="textbox2_PreviewDrop"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: Yes you can create a common method and pass in the parameters. Something like this:

```
    private void textbox_PreviewDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
       string name = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat).ToString();

        TextBox textbox = (TextBox)sender;
        textbox.Text += name;
        textbox.Focus();
        textbox.CaretIndex = textbox.Text.Length;
        e.Handled = true;
        bool remove = _UsersList.Remove((User)listbox1.SelectedItem);
    }

   <TextBox x:Name="textbox1"  
              AcceptsReturn="True"
              AllowDrop="True" 
              DragOver="textbox1_DragOver"
              PreviewDrop="textbox_PreviewDrop" 

  <TextBox x:Name="textbox2"  
              AcceptsReturn="True"
              AllowDrop="True" 
              DragOver="textbox2_DragOver"
              PreviewDrop="textbox_PreviewDrop"
```

Question 2: Your code looks right. You will have to check for Null/Empty for each textbox. I don't see a better way.

Comment: correct (for the first question) but how I pass it to the xaml ,at the end of the post I add the xaml reference to the text boxes

Comment: You still have individual events for the PreviewDrop but move the code to a common method and call it. See my udpdated code above

Comment: I have used the code you proposed ,it look nicer but when I change to it now im able to drag new person to text box that already filled,how can I avoid it?

Comment: its look avoiding this code     (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox2.Text)
                || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox3.Text)) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox4.Text))

Comment: None of the functionality should change. Are you saying something stopped working?

Comment: yes before when I use the code like in the post you cannot drag person to field that already have person inside,any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Have ***one common handler*** for all textBoxes. You can *get textBox from the sender*:

```
private void textbox_PreviewDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    string name = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat).ToString();
    textBox.Text += name;
    textBox.Focus();
    textBox.CaretIndex = textBox.Text.Length;
    e.Handled = true;
    bool remove = _UsersList.Remove((User)listbox1.SelectedItem);
}
```

Comment: Thanks,but now im able to drag new person to text box that already filled,how can I avoid it?